# ARC , stringWithUTF8String memory increase steadily “Live Bytes”

Tags: ios, memory, automatic-ref-counting, memory-leaks

I'm using **ARC** , each time I  **call** the below code . I find the "Live Bytes" will increase a little every time .there must have memory leak here.

```
char* example = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1);                                

label.text = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:example];
```

but if I do in the way below, the memory will keep stable on one number of bytes forever. but the label.text content is not the exact word I want , it's corrupt like "*&#(*&(*@#)#@$".

```
char* example = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1);                                

label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",example];
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but still actual:

It's likely an "autorelease problem" as @jlegakis already pointed out.

I just want to propose a different approach to get rid of the autoreleased returned object from *class factory methods* like `[NSFoo fooWith...]`:

Instead, if you use the pattern

```
NSFoo* foo = [[NSFoo alloc] initWith...]
```

the created object is not autoreleased. So, if you write:

```
char* example = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1);
label.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:example];
```

the "autorelease problem" should be gone.

Answer (score 0):

Try reading the string this way and see if any change occurs.

```
char* example = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1);                                

label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",example];
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the exact same problem.  It turned out to be because stringWithUTF8String was using autorelease internally, so the memory wasn't freed until the end of the enclosing autorelease pool block (which in my case was the entire app).

As an experiment, try this:

```
@autoreleasepool {
  char* example = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1);                                
  label.text = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:example];
}
```

and you should see the live bytes stop growing.